# how do i customise the c3.js chart to get like this

Tags: d3.js, charts, pie-chart, c3.js, donut-chart

[image: donot or pie chart]
Trying to create the above using c3.js.
We are using the same charting library across the application so would like to keep it consistent. Didn't find a way in c3.js to either customize donut or pie chart to get this. i need it to be hour, instead of percentage . and also the target value should be 12 instead of 100%. Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.
normal [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk3htaoc/1/) link to customise.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
 bindto: '#pie-chart',
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 30],
        ['data2', 120],
    ],
    type : 'donut',
    onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
    onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
    onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
},
donut: {
    title: "Iris Petal Width"
}
});

setTimeout(function () {
chart.load({
    columns: [
        ["setosa", 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
        ["versicolor", 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3],

    ]
});
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function () {
chart.unload({
    ids: 'data1'
});
chart.unload({
    ids: 'data2'
});
}, 2500);
```

Comment: https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/85

Comment: @ShekharPankaj thanks for your response for this. i saw the comment  in github as to do like `donut.label.format = function (value, ratio) { return value; } ` , but i didn't get how to pass the value and ratio into it. can you please guide me, how to use it. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I'm pretty close to what you were wanting. The `onrendered` callback code is to append a circle in the middle of that; you may want to handle that another way, my implementation is pretty basic.

The key things to pay attention to are the config options under `gauge`:

```
    gauge: {
      fullCircle: true, // This makes it go all the way around
      max: 12, // This is your max unit -- 12h
      min: 0, // Min. is 0
      startingAngle: 90, // This sets the opening to the other side
      width: 25, // This is how thick the outer arc is.
      label: {
        format: function(value, ratio) {
          return value + 'HR';
        }
      }
```

[image: End result]

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 10],
        ],
        type: 'gauge',
        colors: {
         data1: '#9873FF'
        }
    },
    gauge: {
      fullCircle: true, // This makes it go all the way around
      max: 12, // This is your max unit -- 12h
      min: 0, // Min. is 0
      startingAngle: 90, // This sets the opening to the other side
      width: 25, // This is how thick the outer arc is
      label: {
        format: function(value, ratio) {
    return value + 'HR';
        }
      }
    },
    onrendered: function() {
      setTimeout(function(){ // timeout is needed for initial render.
        var centerBBox = d3.select('.c3-arc-data1').node().getBBox();

        d3.select('.c3-arcs-data1')
        .insert('circle', '.c3-arc-data1')
        .classed('c3-arc-data1-background', true)
        .attr('cx', centerBBox.x + centerBBox.width/2)
        .attr('cy', centerBBox.y + centerBBox.height/2)
        .attr('fill', '#6C40E8')
        .attr('r', (centerBBox.height / 2 - 25)) // "25" is an arbitrary number
      }, 0);
    }
});
```

```css
.c3-chart-arcs-gauge-max, 
.c3-chart-arcs-gauge-min,
.c3-chart-arcs-background{
  display: none;
  }

.c3-gauge-value {
  fill: white !important;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px !important;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.c3-arc-data1 {
  stroke: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/c3js/c3/0.4.11/c3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/c3js/c3/0.4.11/c3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```